# How to open link inside the pdf in webview flutter

Tags: flutter, webview, pdf-viewer, url-launcher

I have added a pdfviewer in my Apps using Library flutter: flutter_cached_pdfview
some part of the code:

```
import 'package:flutter_cached_pdfview/flutter_cached_pdfview.dart';
  
  goToReading(String link){
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_)=> PDF(
          enableSwipe: true,
          swipeHorizontal: false,
          autoSpacing: false,
          pageFling: false,
          onError: (error) {
            print(error.toString());
          },
          onPageError: (page, error) {
            print('$page: ${error.toString()}');
          },
        ).fromUrl(link,
            placeholder: (progress) => Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              body: Center(
                child: Lottie.asset(
                  'assets/images/data.json',
                  height: 200,
                  controller: _controller,
                  onLoaded: (composition) {
                    _controller..duration = composition.duration..forward();
                  },
                ),
              ),
            )
        )
    ));
  }
```

What I want is to open every link inside the pdf to open in webview for now it open in external browser (Chrome, safari),

************************************************************************I want it to open in internal webview inside the app it may be possible by using urllauncher but i dont know how to use it,

---

[See this to understand my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10i3Z.jpg)

---

[See this to understand the current status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeC4V.gif)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `onLinkHandle` and `preventLinkNavigation:true` in your file.

On `onLinkHandle`, you can set it to open `WebView` inside your app instead of opening the browser for it. Becuase by default it will always open web browser if you don't specify those things.

Comment: Thank you sir for commenting , Can you write the code for onlinkhandle to open webview, I dont know how to do it.